# Merge two regex expressions

Tags: regex

I'm having difficulties to merge two regex expressions.

Because i'm not so familiar with it i wrote regexes separetely:

1) No letters can be more than twice in a row, the symbols "'" and "-" are allowed too:

```
^(?!.*([A-Za-z])\1{2})[-'A-Za-z]{3,50}$
```

2) There can not be two allowed symbols in a row:

```
^(?!.*([A-Za-z])\1{2})[-'A-Za-z]{3,50}$
```

It fixes the "--" and "''" issue, but still need to think a way to dissalow "-'" or "'-"

I'm trying to merge them in one, like so:

```
^(?!.*([A-Za-z])\1{2}|([-'])(?!\2))[-'A-Za-z]{3,50}$
```

But seems like my hands are broken. Please tell me where is my mistake?

What i want to achieve:

1) No more than 2 same **letters** in a row.

Pass: `Test`, `Teest`
Fail: `Teeest`, `tttest`

2) No more than 1 special (only two are allowed - ' and -) symbol in a row.

Pass: `Te-st`, `tes't`, `-test`, `'test`, `test-`, `test'`, `T-e-s-t`
Not pass: `Te--st`, `tes''t`, `-'test`, `'-test`, `test'-`, `test-'`

3) Minimum is 3 **letters** ( special symbols do not count ) and maximum is 50 symbols ( **special symbols count** )

Pass: `Te-s-t`, `tes't`, `-test`, `'test`, `test-`, `test'`
Not pass: `te-`, `-te`, `t-e`, `'t'`

Comment: You mean  three consecutive letters cannot appear in a row and each `'` or `-` should be surrounded with letters? Try `^(?!.*([A-Za-z])\1{2})(?=.{3,50}$)[A-Za-z]+(?:[-'][A-Za-z]+)*$`. Without test cases, it is rather difficult to check if the pattern is what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i have updated my question with test cases

Comment: Regexes 1) and 2) seem to be identical. (You use the same numbering again in the rules, but I'm talking about the regexes near the top.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!.*([A-Za-z])\1{2})(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){3,})(?!.{51})[-']?[A-Za-z]+(?:[-'][A-Za-z]+)*[-']?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kB9pH5/1) (with `\n` inside `[^a-zA-Z]` character class just for the demo purposes).

Here is the explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*([A-Za-z])\1{2})` - no 3 identical letters are allowed in a row
- `(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){3,})` - at least 3 (both consecutive and non-consecutive) letters are required
- `(?!.{51})` - a string cannot be longer than 50 symbols long

  *End of zero-width checks, now, consuming the characters:*
- `[-']?` - one or zero `-` or `'` at the beginning of a string
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1 or more letters
- `(?:[-'][A-Za-z]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of:

  - `[-']` - a `'` or `-`
  - `[A-Za-z]+` - 1+ letters (this effectively disallowed consecutive `-` and `'`)
- `[-']?` - one or zero `-` or `'` at the end of a string
- `$` - end of string